# How can I demonstrate the internal energy of diatomic gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

I want to demonstrate the formula to find the internal energy of an ideal gas. The formula is

$$U = \frac{5}{2}nRT.$$

I first tried to use the formula $U = E_c + E_p$
(Internal energy of an ideal gas is equal to the sum of the kinetic energy of all particles and the potential energy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that by applying the [Equipartition Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem). This theorem says that the average value of every quadratic term in the total energy of a molecule is $kT/2$. So write down the energy of a molecule, taking into account its kinetical (which shall include center of mass and rotational terms) and potential energy (which for your case must be zero, since you are considering a rigid molecule) and you shall get five quadratic terms. Hence every molecule has $5kT/2$ on avarege. Sum up over the molecules and use $Nk=nR$, where $N$ is the number of molecules.